# Is there a need to call Tcl_Init on interp created inside tcl code

Tags: tcl

Lets say we have a code like

```
Tcl_interp* master = Tcl_CreateInterp();
Tcl_Init(master);
Tcl_Eval(interp, "interp create slave");
Tcl_Interp* slave = Tcl_GetSlave(interp, "slave");
```

Is there a need to call Tcl_Init on slave interp in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've got the slave interpreter like that, it is already initialised. The initialisation happens during the execution of the `interp create slave` command; the command doesn't finish until that slave interpreter is available for use. All the `Tcl_GetSlave` function is doing is looking up the existing slave interpreter by name relative to the context master interpreter (which you're passing in via the `interp` argument).

You *might* wish to do further configuration on the slave before running scripts in it (such as setting up aliases to allow the slave to call privileged operations in the master) but that's always been a post-`Tcl_Init` thing. Indeed, `Tcl_Init` is intended to only really be called from a context where it's initialising library access from the main interpreter; it's not typically called from slave interpreters at all. The Tcl sources include this comment on the `Tcl_Init` function:

```c
/*
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Tcl_Init --
 *
 *  This function is typically invoked by Tcl_AppInit functions to find
 *  and source the "init.tcl" script, which should exist somewhere on the
 *  Tcl library path.
 *
 * Results:
 *  Returns a standard Tcl completion code and sets the interp's result if
 *  there is an error.
 *
 * Side effects:
 *  Depends on what's in the init.tcl script.
 *
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
```

**tl;dr:** You don't need to bother calling `Tcl_Init` on the slave interpreter.